# Check if a JSON attribute exists

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm trying to check if certain attributes exist in `JSON` data, which is stored as a dictionary:

```py
import json

testJsonString = """
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": {
                "x": "Value One",
                "y": "Value Two"
            }
        }
    }
}
"""

testDict = json.loads(testJsonString)

if 'a' in testDict:
    if 'b' in testDict['a']:
        if 'c' in testDict['a']['b']:
            if 'x' in testDict['a']['b']['c']:
                print(testDict['a']['b']['c']['x'])
            if 'y' in testDict['a']['b']['c']:
                print(testDict['a']['b']['c']['y'])
```

This prints, as desired:

```
Value One
Value Two
```

However, if one of the top level nested attributes is `null` (converted to `None` by `json.loads()`):

```py
testJsonString = """
{
    "a": {
        "b": null
    }
}
"""
```

I get the following error:

```py
if 'c' in testDict['a']['b']:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Is there a way to handle this? I'm stumped.

Comment: Make sure it's not None before you check to see if it contains `'c'`. Because of short-circuiting, you can just do `if testDict['a']['b'] and 'c' in testDict['a']['b']:` Or, just catch the `TypeError`

Comment: or use jsonschema

Comment: `if 'a' in testDict and isinstance(testDict['a'], dict):`

Comment: It might be simpler to use `try/except`.

Answer (score 1):

Working with nested dicts in Python is a pain, I recommend using: https://github.com/cdgriffith/Box

```
from box import Box

def unwrap(b: Box) -> Optional[Box]:
    return None if b == Box() else b

box = Box(testDict)
value = unwrap(box.a.b.c.x)
if value is not None:
    print(value)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a user defined function to check with null safety

```
import json

def Check(key, col):
    return key in col if col is not None else False

testJsonString = """
{
    "a": {
        "b": null
    }
}
"""

testDict = json.loads(testJsonString)

if Check('a', testDict):
    if Check('b', testDict['a']):
        if Check('c', testDict['a']['b']):
            if Check('x', testDict['a']['b']['c']):
                print(testDict['a']['b']['c']['x'])
            if Check('y', testDict['a']['b']['c']):
                print(testDict['a']['b']['c']['y'])
```

Another option a quick one but a dirty approach to handle errors is by using try/except

```
import json

testJsonString = """
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": {
                "x": "Value One",
                "y": "Value Two"
            }
        }
    }
}
"""

testDict = json.loads(testJsonString)

try:
    if 'a' in testDict:
        if 'b' in testDict['a']:
            if 'c' in testDict['a']['b']:
                if 'x' in testDict['a']['b']['c']:
                    print(testDict['a']['b']['c']['x'])
                if 'y' in testDict['a']['b']['c']:
                    print(testDict['a']['b']['c']['y'])
except:
    print('Something went wrong in the dictionary')
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by adding a `None` check for every `if` level. Not sure if this is the best way to go about it, but it works:

```
testJsonString = """
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": {
                "x": "Value One",
                "y": "Value Two"
            }
        }
    }
}
"""

testDict = json.loads(testJsonString)

if testDict and 'a' in testDict:
    if testDict['a'] and 'b' in testDict['a']:
        if testDict['a']['b'] and 'c' in testDict['a']['b']:
            if testDict['a']['b']['c'] and 'x' in testDict['a']['b']['c']:
                print(testDict['a']['b']['c']['x'])
            if testDict['a']['b']['c'] and 'y' in testDict['a']['b']['c']:
                print(testDict['a']['b']['c']['y'])
```